# Script to convert Shift + Spacebar into four spaces on SE

Tags: javascript, stackexchange

I've posted [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234662/should-shift-spacebar-create-a-tab-indent-in-se) and would like to improve the code involved to handle a few "bugs" (not that it's necessary to provide such code, just for my own practice), but [I doubt I'm doing it as efficiently as possible with my updated conditions for the feature](http://jsfiddle.net/9fYyU/11/):

```
$("textarea").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 32) {
        var white = " ",
            pad = "    ",
            t = this.value,
            n = this.selectionStart,
            s = this.scrollTop,
            r = [t.slice(0, n), t.slice(n)];
        if (r[0].indexOf(white, r[0].length - 1) !== -1) {
            this.value = r.join(pad);
            this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = n + pad.length;
            this.scrollTop = s;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

---

### Purpose:

- **Most importantly**, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> creates 4 spaces, cancelling the default space action.
- Also to avoid accidental usage, it should not execute unless the character before the cursor is a space, or empty. (Avoids `"XML is..."` becoming `"XML    is..."`). *I couldn't figure out how to check for either whitespace OR a new line, so if someone could mention how that's done, it would be helpful, but if not I can always ask on SO.*
- To avoid a (reported) potential bug:

  > the scrollTop property of long textareas must be involved because re-setting the .value to insert the tab can cause a scroll [in some browsers]

---

### Review

**I'm looking for general improvements, best practices, shortening opportunities, simplification, etc.** I'd particularly like to learn a better method / trick for figuring out if the previous character doesn't contain a non-space character rather than checking for either nothing or a space.

Comment: Oops, I made a change there that I didn't test and I've got variable conditions there that are out of scope! fail...

Comment: Ok, fixed. I'm working with techniques I learned recently, so I wasn't able to properly implement a check for a new line (no space or char). Go ahead and review this as is, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) to grab the preceding character and check it against a space, newline, or empty string (the case when the cursor is at the start). But let's not stop there.

- `white` and `pad` are okay enough (`white` is probably unnecessary, but `space` would be a better name since newlines are typically included in the generic term "whitespace"), but those other names are *truly horrible!*
- You should probably maintain their full text selection--beginning and end.

Updated code:

```
$("textarea").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 32) {
        var pad = "    ",
            text = this.value,
            start = this.selectionStart,
            end = this.selectionEnd,
            scroll = this.scrollTop,
            before = text.slice(0, start),
            after = text.slice(start),
            prevChar = before.charAt(before.length - 1);
        if (prevChar === "" || prevChar === " " || prevChar === "\n") {
            this.value = before + pad + after;
            this.selectionStart = start + pad.length;
            this.selectionEnd = end + pad.length;
            this.scrollTop = scroll;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Here are some future enhancement ideas:

- Search for the preceding newline to ensure there is only whitespace before the cursor. This would fully stop expansion inside a sentence. Right now you can still insert four spaces in the middle right after a space.
- Consider using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> so you can add <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>  + <kbd>space</kbd> for outdenting.
- Shift/unshift every selected line instead of just the cursor position. Right now the <kbd>{ }</kbd> button can be wrangled to do shifting, but it's cumbersome since you have to put some non-space character on the first line to get indentation.

Comment: For tabbing x2, x3, x4 etc for deeper code indents, being able to insert the spaces in the middle after a space appears necessary.

Comment: Off topic for the review maybe, but ***how*** seriously do you want bullets 2 & 3 personally? I'd recommend the preference of keeping Shift + Space *(Everybody gets the concept of Shift + Letter = uppercase letter and a tab is sort of like an uppercase space. Let's ignore the fact that we're not actually using tabs.)* -- Instead, I think Alt + Shift + Space is likely easier to remember for outdenting, because Alt[ernate] of Shift + Space.

Comment: @jt0dd I edit copy-paste code very often, and that immediately drops one indentation level. Allowing me to select lines of text to in/outdent is key. As for the bindings, on Windows and Linux when it comes to switching applications, tabs, and indentation, shift means "opposite". Plus, many coders are used to ctrl + space for expansion.

Comment: I posted [a secondary review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55733/script-to-convert-shift-spacebar-into-four-spaces-on-se-second-improvement) after utilizing your review among other big changes.